# Scared enemies run into walls

Tags: 3d, navmesh, gdscript, godot-3, kinematic

I set up a basic pyramid shaped enemy kinematic body that runs away from the player when its health is too low and runs towards the player if the enemy has enough health. The enemy also turns to face the player if they are chasing the player or turn its back to the player when running away, so very basic.

But I realized that when the enemy is low on HP and running away, they can be chased into a wall. For some enemies that is ok as I wanted to let them be able to climb so once the climb function is done for the enemies that will be just fine.

But other enemies can't climb so they just run into walls like fools, which is fine for a horror movie but not for this game because it tries to have a minimum of realism and not even a chicken is that stupid.

How do I fix this? I see a lot of people mentioning 'navmeshes' but can I turn terrain made in blender into a navmesh? How does that even work? From the tutorials I've seen everyone who uses navmesh as a terrain is only dealing with boxes and planes.